# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: jackson, jackson2, jackson-dataformat-xml, jackson-databind

when deserializing below JSON, it fails with above exception message  when trying to parse the server attribute  which has its type 'string' nested  within it, how to parse a JSON which is having the attribute types nested within each attribute like below?

```
{
  "header": {
    "time": 1492178674232,
    "threadId": null,
    "requestMarker": null,
    "env": null,
    **"server": {
      "string": "astapp078"
    }**,
    "service": {
      "string": "ApiCalendarsEntityStreamPublisher"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@JsonProperty` annotation to specify a different name for the JSON field than the POJO field. And wrap the `server` and `service` fields in classes. E.g.

```
class POJO {
    Server server;
    Service service;
}

class Server {
    @JsonProperty("string") String name;
}

class Service {
    @JsonProperty("string") String name;
}
```

And `name` in `server` would be `"astapp078"`

Comment: i dont have access to the source files or any control how its serialized,  as i am reading this message from a kafka topic. I only have the .class files as a dependency to parse these messages back to java object.